# Perl not recognizing module / module path for root user

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cpan, cpanm, locallib

I am new to Perl so please bear with me. Thank you for your assistance.

I have an Ubuntu machine with Perl on it. I followed the [local::lib bootstrapping guide](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib#The-bootstrapping-technique)

I used cpanm to install DBI and other modules to my system. I am concerned there may be other DBI modules available on my system which could be part of the problem. This is the result of `find / -name 'DBI.pm' 2>/dev/null`:

```
/home/ubuntu/.cpanm/work/16125643.6178/DBI-1.643/blib/lib/DBI.pm
/home/ubuntu/.cpanm/work/16125643.6178/DBI-1.643/blib/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
/home/ubuntu/.cpanm/work/16125643.6178/DBI-1.643/DBI.pm
/home/ubuntu/.cpanm/work/16125643.6178/DBI-1.643/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
/home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/DBI.pm
/home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Bundle/DBI.pm
```

I added 2 lines to my .bashrc file. (I added the second line because I broke things for the non-root user and this fixed it; maybe I broke something with local::lib?)

```
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
PERL5LIB="/home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5"
```

I can run my perl script as a non-root user.
If I run with `sudo perlScript.pl` I get this error: `Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBI module)`

I have been troubleshooting @INC for a while now and cannot figure out how to adjust it for the root user. I have tried various things including adding PERL5LIB to .profile and calling my script like so: `sudo sh -c '. ~/.profile; perl ~/perlScripts/perlScript.pl "argForScript"'` (I verified that PERL5LIB is being set with `sudo sh -c '. ~/.profile; echo $PERL5LIB'`)

However I always get the @INC error. The most obvious thing I have noticed is comparing `sudo perl -V` and `perl -V`. The sudo call does not show any ENV vars and the @INC does not include the desired PERL5LIB location. The non-sudo call does show the desired ENV and @INC vars.

I am considering wiping things and doing a fresh install with root privileges for local::lib and cpan. Not really sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: For what reason do you build a local library for user 'ubuntu' and don't you install the Perl modules globally when at the end your scripts have to run as 'root'?

Comment: *"If I run with sudo ..."* Why would you run it with `sudo` ? When you installed `local::lib` you installed it for user `ubuntu` so it will not work for another user like `root`

Comment: Re "*I am considering wiping things and doing a fresh install with root privileges for local::lib and cpan. Not really sure what else to try at this point.*", That's not going to prevent sudo from not passing on PERL5LIB. Setting PERL5LIB inside of sudo will do the trick.

Comment: I prefer to install my own Perl rather than using local::lib. `perlbrew` can help with that.

Comment: If you install modules for / owned by the 'ubuntu' user and then let root user use them, you now have  a security hole whereby the ubuntu user can escalate to root privileges. Stuff executed by root should be owned by root.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I need to run with sudo for access to certain files so I am going to try a fresh install with sudo. I'm wary of using sudo to install things which is why I setup local::lib initially. I will also take a look at perlbrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the commands that ended up working for me. I corrupted my first environment with local::lib / non-sudo cpan install, so I setup a fresh VM.

```
sudo apt install make
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo cpan App::cpanminus
cpanm --sudo DBI
cpanm --sudo Array::Utils
cpanm --sudo DBD::mysql
```